# JDeveloper подчеркивает первую строчку в try и выдает ошибку

Tags: java

```
 java.net.URI uri;

    void openURL()
    {      
        try
        {
            uri = new URI("http://www.google.com/");
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);
        }

        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (URISyntaxException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: JDeveloper Studio 11.1.2.1.0 выдает ошибку: "Error(17,19): incompatible types"

Comment: Eclipse молча выполняет

Comment: Может, из-за неправильного импорта, uri  - откуда?

Comment: java.net.URI uri = new URI("http://www.google.com/");
надеюсь, я правильно понял вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, возможно, так надо,

```
java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI("http://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: Gorets, спасибо!!!!